# Running Tomcat 7 on Amazon ec2 but can't see welcome in browser

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have Tomcat version 7 installed on an Amazon EC2 AMI running Amazon Linux. When I start tomcat as a service I get 'OK'. I confirmed that port 8080 is open for incoming on the firewall security group for my AMI. However, I still don't get anything in my browser when I try to connect to it. I get just a blank white page at:

```
myAMI'sIPAddress:8080
```

when I shut down tomcat and try again I get 'this web page is not available'. So I know that starting and stopping tomcat are producing differents result in my browser consistently. The question is how come I get a blank white page and I am not seeing tomcat's default welcome page? Here is some more diagnostic info:

```
$ sudo service tomcat7 stop    [  OK  ]
$ sudo service tomcat7 start   [  OK  ]
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 8080
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      5754/java
$ sudo service tomcat7 status
$ ..                           [  OK  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a webapp installed? You probably won't see anything if there's nothing in your webapps directory. Or, if there is a war file, then put its name on the end of your request:

```
http://example.com:8080/appname
```

Comment: Shouldn't it still show the welcome page even if there are no web applications deployed?

Comment: I don't think so, it will probably just give you a 404. There's a 'welcome' app, I think, which may or may not be deployed.